# Why in JavaScript parent variable takes the value of child variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me please with next problem.

```
var a = _b; //_b and _c is arguments. _b is array of objects (length = 1), _c is integer value
if (a.length != 0)
{
   $.each(a,function(k,v){
     if (v.c!= _c)
       a.splice(k,1);//here a becomes empty, but _b becomes empty too. i don't know why.
   }); 
   if (a.length != 0){
      _b = a;
   }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like obfuscated code to me.

Comment: `a` and `_b` refer to the same object.

Comment: If the intent is to filter items out of `_b`, have a look at [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Comment: thanks, Jonathan. your comment very usefull to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `a` is a reference to the array `_b`, not a copy, so emptying `a` empties `_b` too.

Comment: thanks, nrabinowitz. then tell me please how make copy.

Comment: There are several ways - I usually use a = _b.slice()